# How can i use the HTTP_REFERER to come from a specified domain name

Tags: php

I know the HTTP_REFERER method has a security loop, but it most cases it works fine. How can i use it, to limit how a user see other pages on my website, instead of just directly clicking on the link or pasting it on the browser. Specifically, i want the referer to only work if the referred url came from the same domain name? And not from another source.

Comment: I hope you are not using it to keep a user logged in instead of using sessions or protected directories.

Answer (score 1):

With Apache, to protect a directory (e.g. your `/images` directory) something like this in a `.htaccess` file works:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST};%{HTTP_REFERER} !^([^;]+);http://\1(/.*)?$
RewriteRule .* /please_dont_hotlink.html [R]
```